# Links not going back a directory?

Tags: html, broken-links

I have a website, let's call it `example.com`. Within this site, I have some FAQs but the person that built the site saved the FAQ pages under a directory on the site named "FAQs".

As an example an FAQ page would be located at:

`example.com/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`.

Note the `pages/en/` directory. Ideally I would like all the pages to be saved under `example.com/index.html` etc but I can't change this.

Anyway, when I am on any of these FAQ pages, and I try to link back to say the home page `index.html` the navigation won't go to the page. So for example, when I am on:

`example.com/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`

and I try to link back to the home page

`example.com/pages/en/index.html` (which is where the index page is saved) the nav won't work. Instead it will try to go to `example.com/pages/en/faqs/index.html`.

Now I am assuming this happens because I am in the "faq" directory, but how do I go back to the root directory when linking? The code for the link is simply `<a href="index.html">Home</a>`. I could of course just put in the full link `example.com/pages/en/index.html`, which would solve this but is there another way around this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to give a relative file path of `<a href="../index.html">Home</a>`

Alternately you can specify a link from the root of your site with
`<a href="/pages/en/index.html">Home</a>`

`..` and `.` have special meanings in file paths, `..` means up one directory and `.` means current directory.

so `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` is the same as `<a href="./index.html">Home</a>`

Comment: Thanks to you both. I've tried this and it works. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 23):

There are two type of paths: absolute and relative. This is basically the same for files in your hard disc and directories in a URL.

Absolute paths start with a leading slash. They always point to the same location, no matter where you use them:

- `/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`

Relative paths are the rest (all that do not start with slash). The location they point to *depends* on where you are using them

- `index.html` is:

  - `/pages/en/faqs/index.html` if called from `/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`
  - `/pages/index.html` if called from `/pages/example.html`
  - etc.

There are also two special directory names: `.` and `..`:

- `.` means "current directory"
- `..` means "parent directory"

You can use them to build relative paths:

- `../index.html` is `/pages/en/index.html` if called from `/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`
- `../../index.html` is `/pages/index.html` if called from `/pages/en/faqs/faq-page1.html`

Once you're familiar with the terms, it's easy to understand what it's failing and how to fix it. You have two options:

- Use absolute paths
- Fix your relative paths

Comment: great answer! this was very instructive

Answer (score 9):

To go up a directory in a link, use `..`.  This means "go up one directory", so your link will look something like this:

```
<a href="../index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, new it was just me being dumb :)