# How can we call the .js file from html file residing in different directories in iOS SDK?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have dragged a folder named mydocs and selected the "create folder references." option in coy menu.
Here is my folder hierarchy.

```
|- mydocs
    |- newfolder
        |- anothernewfolder
            |- js
                |- main.js
        |- view
            |- html
                |- index.html
```

I have to call the main.js file from index.html file.
For now I am using the absolute path "user/...../mydocs/newfolder/anothernewfolder/js/main.js"
for including the file. It works like charm on simulator but when I run this on device I doesn't gets called.

How to call the .js files from the .html file residing in different directories?

After searching over the internet I found this **answer** in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862231/links-not-going-back-a-directory) and by looking at it
`../../anothernewfolder/js/main.js` worked for me as `..` means up one directory and `.` means current directory.
So I have to go up two time for finding the directory of the .js files.

**But I am unable to find how the .js file can refer to another .js file of different directory?**

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following code in your  index.html

```
../anothernewfolder/js/main.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call main.js like this in index.html in view folder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../anothernewfolder/js/main.js"></script>
```