# How to give the background-image path in CSS?

Tags: html, css

My CSS file is in :

Project/Web/Support/Styles/file.css

My image is in :

Project/Web/images/image.png

I want this image in my CSS file.

I have tried :

```
1) background-image: url(/images/image.png);
2) background-image: url('/images/image.png');
3) background-image: url("/images/image.png");
4) background-image: url(../images/image.png);
5) background-image: url('../images/image.png');
6) background-image: url("../images/image.png");
```

But. i'm not getting this image in my page.

What is the correct way to specify the path of image file in the css file ?

Comment: This might help...(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862231/links-not-going-back-a-directory)

Comment: You should try avoid using Relative paths if possible and instead use an Absolute path.

Comment: Its used in a jsp file.

Comment: Using absolute path has some limitations. That's why i went for relative path.

Comment: Relative background image URLs are relative to the path of the css file they are declared in, not to the HTML file as other resources are. Check http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#uri

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Your css is here: `Project/Web/Support/Styles/file.css`

1 time `../` means `Project/Web/Support` and 2 times `../` i.e. `../../` means Project/Web

Try:

```
background-image: url('../../images/image.png');
```

Comment: Yes, correct. Similarly, if you give `././`, you would get the same solution. - @Hiral

Comment: so the path is relative to current CSS and not the HTML in which the CSS is included right?

Comment: **Question:**  **../** means go back go back? that's why we are at Project/Web/Support but won't **../../** means only we are at Project. Then  the code shouldn't be **background-image: url('../../Web/images/image.png');**?  I'm unable to understand please explain. @Hiral

Comment: @HarshalSharma we have to reach at /Project/Web. 1 time ../ -> /Project/Web?Support and 2 times ../ i.e. ../../ will take us to /Project/Web. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Hiral ok, we are not counting file.css. ../ => Project/Web/Support and ../../ means /Project/Web. So, one ../ will take you one directory back. is that it?

Comment: @HarshalSharma yes exactly!

Answer (score 16):

There are two basic ways:

```
url(../../images/image.png)
```

or

```
url(/Web/images/image.png)
```

I prefer the latter, as it's easier to work with and works from all locations in the site (so useful for inline image paths too).

Mind you, I wouldn't do so much deep nesting of folders. It seems unnecessary and makes life a bit difficult, as you've found.

Answer (score 6):

Use the below.

```
background-image: url("././images/image.png");
```

This shall work.

Comment: `.` refers to the current folder, `..` refers to the parent directory and that one should be used.

Comment: The level holds that you are targetting it by `././` to reach to the parent folder. Try it yourself. - @AdrianBer

Answer (score 4):

You need to get 2 folders back from your css file.

**Try:**

```
background-image: url("../../images/image.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also add inline css for adding image as a background as per below example

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url(../../foo.png);">
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

once done this the image folder no longer shalt put it. only be

```
background-image: url ( "/ image.png");
```

carpera that the image is already in the static files