# can't find correct relative paths of CSS background-image

Tags: html, css, image

I am studying HTML and CSS right now. And I got issue about relative paths of CSS background-image. My background-image code under CSS doesn't show image when I use relative path.

I am using ATOM code editor. here is the CSS linked code in my HTML file.

```
<link href="resources\css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I try several relative paths, all doesn't work

1. `background-image: url('resources\building.png');`
2. `background-image: url('\resources\building.png');`
3. `background-image: url('boardway\resources\building.png');`
4. `background-image: url('\boardway\resources\building.png');`
5. `background-image: url('C:\Users\michael\gitprojects\boardway\resources\building.png');`

`boardway` is parent directory of `resources`. `C:\Users\..\..` is absolute path of image. All five address don't work.

But When I use AWS address which is

```
background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/programs/freelance-one/broadway/images/the-flatiron-building.png');
```

The background picture are showing correctly. So at least I can sure my code is correct. But I failed to input a correct relative path. What I can do?

Comment: 1)where is path html? 2)where is path css?

Comment: Relative paths in CSS are relative to your CSS-file, and if you want to go upwards in your hierarchy you use dots. so if your image is in `C:\Users\michael\gitprojects\boardway\resources\building.png` and your css is in `C:\Users\michael\gitprojects\boardway\css\styles.css` then your relative path would be `../resources/building.png`

Comment: Possible Duplicate.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047364/how-to-give-the-background-image-path-in-css

Comment: The 5th one is not a relative path, it's an absolute path. And browsers generally don't allow you to load absolute local paths (security issues), at least not without making you hop through hoops first.

Answer (score 5):

you should put `/` all url's

```
url('resources/building.png');
```

[Please read about URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link you posted. I finally found what the issue is. I think the css file didn't know where is the basic/Absolute URL is. That why relative path didn't work. I change my image location to C:\Users\michael\gitprojects\boardway\resources\css\images. The the relative path 'images/building.png' worked smoothly

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways for defining path for a file/image/js/css etc.

1. Using Absolute Path

2 .Using Relative Path

Below are few examples

**Relative Paths**

```
index.html
/graphics/image.png
/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

**Absolute Paths**

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/graphics/image.png
http://www.example.com/help/articles/how-do-i-set-up-a-webpage.html
```

[Read More][1]

Issue with your paths
1. Use forward slash instead of a backward slash.
2. Never link file for local systems (Path on the server might differ).

Try to make changes accordingly as per above.

```
Background-images:URL(../resources/building.png);
```

Comment: Your answer is useless if you don't explain it or at least explain the assumptions you are making.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally found what the issue is. I think the css file didn't know where is the basic/Absolute URL is. That why relative path didn't work. I change my image location to C:\Users\michael\gitprojects\boardway\resources\css\images. Then the the relative path 'images/building.png' worked smoothly

Answer (score -1):

**Relative Path worked for me:**

```
    background-image:url('../images/filename.png');
```

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better" . You can read this in help center, [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please read it, and try to add some supporting information