# svg image not showing up in firefox, chrome

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I got an HTML code and when it's a live server (localhost) I can see the .svg image. Once I open the file in firefox or chrome, I cannot see the image.

```css
.status {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.rating {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: var(--light-grayish-magenta);
  font-weight: 800;
  color: var(--very-dark-magenta);
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.rating::before {
  content: '';
  width: 6.25rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(../images/icon-star.svg);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-repeat: space;
}
```

```html
<div class="status flow-content">
  <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in Report Guru</div>
  <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in Reviews</div>
  <div class="rating">Rated 5 Stars in BestTech</div>
</div>
```

Comment: CHECK your browser console , probably the img path isn't correct

Comment: Console has all answers, maybe you didn't put the right path or something...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give the background-image path in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047364/how-to-give-the-background-image-path-in-css)

Comment: I did check the console now and it does say that it's failed to load the file.. I tried the img path, didn't work. I'll try a few other options and see what happens. Thank or the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

it should work if you will wrap your path in single quote

`background-image: url('../images/icon-star.svg');`

or without quote try

`background-image: url(icon-star.svg);`