# How to go back to directory in html?

Tags: html, css, dynamic-html

How to go back to the directory in html. Firstly I will show by folders.

```
My website
├ Pages (folder name)
│  └ about-us.html
├ Css (folder name)
│  └ Style.css
└ index.html
```

Let us assume that we are working on about-us.html. Now I want to connect style.css to about-us.html. If anyone know the answer thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean `<link href="../Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in a.about-us.html and  `<link href="Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />` in index.html

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862231/links-not-going-back-a-directory

Answer (score 1):

To go from `about-us.html` to `style.css`:

Use this to go back `../`

Try this:

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: @AkashKamath What is your CSS file name?

Comment: My css file name: style.css

Comment: An what is the CSS folder name, "`Css`" or "`css`".

Comment: The folder name is css

Comment: I have updated the code above, copy it and paste it in the head section of your `about-us.html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227199/discussion-between-akash-kamath-and-manas-khandelwal).

Comment: Are you there?.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
<link href="../Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in a.about-us.html and

```
<link href="Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in index.html

You can do absolute in both html files:

```
<link href="/Pages/Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or if Pages is the root folder:

```
<link href="/Css/a.Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```